# What color does Reimu's eye have?

Tags: touhou-project

I have seen Zun's artwork in both games and manga. Sometimes he shows that reimu have red eyes and sometimes she have dark brown eyes.

[Ignoring PC-98 games where she have purple eyes]

So what eye color does Hakurei Reimu have by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
 It seems like she appears have brownish-red eyes, but red by default according to most of the Zun works. Also, the brown eyes were actually a bit red, just that it mostly appeared brown if you don't look closely.